# How to calculate the ratio of base lengths of two similar right-angled triangles given the difference of their heights?

Tags: math, geometry, 2d

I'm stuck with this problem, please help. In the [linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FORx.jpg) (also sketch below) I have 2 similar right-angled triangles. I want to calculate the ratio of lengths **a/b**. Is it possible if I only know the length **d** and the angle **t**? Thank you.

PS: This is not homework, it is part of my work. I have a camera that takes images of an object from different unknown distances and I want to predict how much larger or smaller the object will appear, relative to the first image.

[image: 1]

Comment: The problem requires one more piece of information to be solvable. That could be the distance to the object, for example, but it could also be another indirect measurement. If you can determine `a0/b0` for one distance `d0`, then you can calculate `a/b` for any other distance `d`. For example, if you can find the distance `d0` where `a0/b0 = 2` (i.e. the apparent sizes are equal `a0-b0 = b0`), then that would be enough to calculate `a/b` for an arbitrary `d`.

Comment: Thank you @dxiv, this is a very interesting idea. Measuring the distance to the object will probably require to add another piece of hardware to the setup and my boss would like to avoid it. But perhaps I can measure `a0/b0` in my setup which would solve the problem without extra hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible if I only know the length d and the angle t?

No, it's not. You need at least one more known length. Take a look at this figure:

[image]

In both pairs of triangles, `d`, `t` and `(a-b)` are equal. But in right shape `b` is bigger, so `a/b` is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Given the input data, you cannot find `a/b` but you can definitely find a relationship between `a` and `b`. It is just not a ratio. The relationship is

```
a = b + d*tan(t)
```

Or if you prefer, you can deduce the difference between `a` and `b`, i.e.

```
a - b = d*tan(t)
```